# Why only 4 bytes are needed for representing the actual 64-bit number?

Tags: python, numbers, integer

I was reading *Data Structures and Algorithms in Python by  by Michael T. Goodrich,
Roberto Tamassia, Michael H. Goldwasse and came across this sentence*

> On our system, the size of a typical int object requires 14 bytes of
>   memory (well beyond the 4 bytes needed for representing the actual
>   64-bit number).

What caught my attention was *4 bytes needed for representing the actual 64-bit number*.

Why 4 bytes and not 8 bytes (ie. 64 /8)?

Does this have something to do with supporting both 32 and 64 bit operating systems?

This question is not about why int object requires 14 (or more) bytes. I am having difficuly understanding this sentence: *4 bytes needed for representing the actual 64-bit number*.

Comment: The author is just wrong here - probably just a typo.  Of course a 64-bit int requires 8 bytes.

Comment: If the integer is unsigned, then you might only need 32.

Comment: @AdrianMm, you _might_ need only 1 bit ;-)  But in general, a 64-bit int can dead obviously require 8 bytes.  That's what "64-bit" means - same as what "8-byte" means.

Comment: A book as strongly typed as its subject language!